# if a page is loaded using ajax from PHP. how to call a function if page is loaded

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, function

i'm working on php + ajax. 
can somebody help me in following process

1. I made  two divs (one contains manu, and other is target div, where pages are loaded from menu)
2. i loaded a from in terget div.
3. this form adds values to database using php.
4. the next pages respondeds as **data is saved successfully**... in target div
5. now i want to call a javascript function right after text appears "**data is saved successfully**".
6. this function takes the user to the next form...
   if there is any other solution please do let me know. thank you

Comment: So which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

You would do it just like any standard AJAX:

set up the call back function for the AJAX success to check for any status code returned by the PHP code.  If the status code is a success, then do what you want to -- in your case, call the Javascript function.

usually it is easier to use some Javascript library, such as jQuery's AJAX:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

look for the `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` which is the callback function and the examples there.

note that the status code 404 or 200 is different from your own status code.  Your status code can be anything returned as the content of the AJAX call.  Usually, a typical status code of 200 is returned, but that's the code for HTTP, not your status code.

Comment: thank you....You know what... I really didn't want to learn jquery right now... but everywhere excellent work is done in jquery.. and i've learnt it now :)... this is really fun.. no need to type longer scripts... onclick.. and check if exists..etc.. jquery is really fun... It has changed my profile.. thank you man!.

Comment: and the fun is..no need to look for ajax.. one liner ajax function :D:D:D:D: so funny

Comment: this applies even for non-jQuery cases too... just use the callback like in the example:  http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp   when it is `xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200`, then check for any status code in your data returned (or try it without any code...), and call your JS function

Comment: Yes i' see that...w3schools.. is really aowsome website for training... What i've done. i'll show you IA.